# ¿Cómo concatenar un String con código ejecutable?

Tags: java, apex

Si tengo un Objeto (obj) y en un array de String tengo una lista con los nombres API de los campos de ese objeto (Name, Created_By, etc)... 
Cómo podría hacer esto?:

```
for(String field : arrayFields) {
    System.debug( obj.¿¿field?? ) // devolver valor del campo
}
```

Sería algo como convertir el String a "texto de código". No se si me he explicado bien.

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Quizá si pones algún ejemplo podremos entender lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Al final lo he resuelto con las funciones get(fieldName) y put(fieldName, value) que propone esta documentación.